# SOQL Address Country not localized / translated

Tags: soql, translation, country-and-state, address

I'm querying an Account Address and want the country to be translated into the language of the requesting user.

Sample query:

```
SELECT BillingAddress FROM Account
```

I maintained the translation of the country in the translation workbench and already tried to use "toLabel(BillingAddress)" without success.

When referencing the BillingCountry directly I get the same result. Prefixing with "toLabel" results in an error:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: only picklist fields, field history, or platform entity fields (or Record Type Name, Description in the SELECT list) support translation
```

Within the UI the Label is translated:
[image]

Other values in the query are getting translated as well.

Can country and state values be retrieved in the local language using SOQL?

What am I missing?

Is the Country/State picklist not treated as a picklist as referenced in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error hints, what you're pulling (`BillingCountry`) is not a picklist. If you take a look at the [Address Compound Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm) documentation, you'll see the following noted:

- `BillingCountry` is a String
- `BillingCountryCode` is a Picklist

You need to reference `BillingCountryCode` to pull your translated values:

`SELECT toLabel(BillingCountryCode) FROM Account`

Comment: Thank you so much that did the trick!